# Interaction with UIView under UINavigationBar when bar is hidden?

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar

I have UINavigationBar, and UIView under it.
At navigation bar i have UIButton, when i touch button - it hide navigation bar, and my view being visible.
At my view i have button too, but when i touch it - actions does't occur(

Also i tried -

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setAlpha:0.0];
```

and

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

Looking like that my view doesn't have userInteraction(

What may be, or how i can show UIView over UINavigationBar?

Comment: Could you check whether your view receives user touch? Just set breakpoint to the selector that handles touch.